# Is there a Work Around to Get Markups, Issues and RFI Events (Add, Delete, Update) Through Autodesk Webhooks API?

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Is there a Work Around to Get Markups, Issues and RFI Events (Add, Delete, Update) Through Autodesk Webhooks API?

I'm basically trying to capture the events for Issues, RFIs and Markups when there're linked to a spefic file using Webhooks API. Would that be possible?

Comment: unfortunately as I know there is not Webhook API with Issue/RFI. And no API with Markup either.I am checking with engineer team if they have any news on that.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I'm not sure if that would possible, but from my point of view linking an issue to document should trigger "dm.version.modified". I'm looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much!

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Just wanted to check if Issues/RFIs support webhooks API now? I couldn't find in the documentation so thought to check here.

Comment: @SushrutParanjape, I hate to disappoint you. It is still a wish. It has not yet supported webhook with Issue / RFI.